# How do I import variables from NodeJS to JS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, client-side, server-side

How can I use static variables in an JS file?

I'm using nodeJS with ejs templates.
In HTML it works if i use `<%= colors %>` but i want to use the content of color in clientside js.

i think it should look like:

```
var color[] = <%= colors =>
```

would be nice to know what im doing wrong.
Thank you!

Marius

edit:
to clear things up, i've written the question fast so it seems i've forgotten to explain some things.

colors is an array send by the nodeJS express server.

```
var colors = ['blue', 'red', 'green'];
```

in the index.ejs template, i can call "blue" via:

```
<span>    
  <%= colors[0] %>
</span>
```

.
now i have a separate client-side functions.js file.
i want to access "blue" in this file.

Comment: `<%= colors =>` is some markup used by template language like PHP I guess. So either mention that language or clarify your question.

Comment: that is not html, that is a tempting engine, can't pinpoint which one maybe els? You need to clarify more what you want to do and also more context in regards to the tech setup

Comment: Look at the source code that gets delivered to the browser. Look at the JS you get. Look to see if it looks the way you expect. Look to see what errors the browser reports in the Console of the Developer Tools.

Comment: Odds are that `colors` does not conform to the syntax of a JavaScript string literal.

Answer (score 4):

Your first problem is that `var color[] =` is not valid JavaScript.

You seem to be getting it mixed up with PHP. The syntax you are looking for is probably:

```
var color = [];
color.push(someValue);
```

We can't tell what your server side code is going to output for `<%= colors =>` but I'll bet it is something like `blue`.

```
var color = [];
color.push(<?= colors =>);
```

would therefore give you:

```
var color = [];
color.push(blue);
```

… which is fine, so long as you have a variable called `blue` already. You probably want a string literal there, so you need to encode your text as JavaScript literals.

That is more or less the same as JSON so:

```
var color = [];
color.push(<?= JSON.stringify(colors) =>);
```

… will probably do the job.

If `colors` isn't `blue` but is actually an array, then you would probably want to just dump the whole thing to the variable in one go:

```
var color = <?= JSON.stringify(colors) =>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, i found a workaround.

i have now this in my index.ejs template:

```
<script>
  var colors = [<%= colors %>];
</script>
```

and i call my functions.js (client-side) in the next line.
now i can use:

```
$("span").text(colors[0]);
```

.
if there's a better solution (the jquery code isnt exactly what i've used), please comment!